# How and what do Instagram and Vine use to have videos inside their UITableViewCells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, avplayer

i have been looking around the internet and cannot find a method of embedding videos into `UITableViewCells`, similar to the way in which Instagram and Vine embed theres. Do they use `MPMoviePlayer`, `AVPlayer` or something else? Do you know of any tutorials or source code similar that I can take a look at?